# WDF Coinstaller issue

Tags: device-driver, kmdf, wdf

I'm having problem installing my KMDF 1.9 driver on a 32-bit Vista machine running KMDF 1.5. I was hoping the coinstaller should update the Vista machine to KMDF 1.9. But it does not.

What have I missed?

```
[Version]
Signature = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class = MYDevice
ClassGuid = {xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-cccc-dddddddddddd}
Provider = %MyCompany%
DriverVer = 03/04/2013,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile = mydevice.cat

; =================== Class section ===================
[ClassInstall32]
Addreg = MydeviceClassReg     

[MydeviceClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-5

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12

; ================== Device section ===================
[Manufacturer]
%MyCompany% = MyCompany,NTx86,NTamd64

[MyCompany.NTx86]
%DeviceDesc% = mydevice, USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy&REV_zzzz&MI_aa

[MyCompany.NTamd64]
%DeviceDesc% = mydevice, USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy&REV_zzzz&MI_aa

[mydevice]
CopyFiles = mydevice.Files

[mydevice.Files]
mydevice.sys

[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1 = %Disk_Description%,,,\x86

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1 = %Disk_Description%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles]
mydevice.sys  = 1,,

[mydevice.Services]
Addservice = mydevice, 0x00000002, mydevice.AddService

[mydevice.AddService]
DisplayName    = %ClassName%
ServiceType    = 1  ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3  ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1  ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary  = %12%\mydevice.sys


; =========== WDF Coinstaller installation =============
[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles = 11

[mydevice.Dev.NT.Coninstallers]
Addreg = Coinstaller_Addreg
CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
winusbcoinstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[SourceDisksFiles.NTx86]
winusbcoinstaller2.dll = 1
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.NTamd64]
winusbcoinstaller2.dll = 2
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"winusbcoinstaller2.dll","WdfCoInstaller01009.dll"

[mydevice.Wdf]
KmdfService = mydevice, mydevice_wdfsect

[mydevice_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.9

; ======================= Strings ======================
[Strings]
MyCompany        = "MyCompany"
Disk_Description = "My Device Installation Disk"
ClassName        = "MYDEV"
DeviceDesc       = "My Device"
```

The setupapi.dev.log says:

```
!!!  dvi: Device not started: Device has problem: 0x27: CM_PROB_DRIVER_FAILED_LOAD.
```

Everything works fine on Win7 which already got KMDF 1.9

Answer (score 1):

It's not a coinstaller problem. Your log tells you that your device has failed to start. The installation itself completes prior to that. Debug your driver.

Comment: Are you sure? The driver works on 30+ machines except this one... Unfortunatly I'm not able to debug on this very machine. Just to be sure. If I install my KMDF 1.9 driver on a Vista with KMDF 1.5 is the KMDF supposed to update to 1.9 with help from the co-installer?